# Select2 4.0.x Multi Checkboxes JS Plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I'm using the `Select2` control along with the `Select2.Multi-checkboxes.JS` plugin to allow multi-checkbox selection.

The following demo shows that the control works properly with **Select2 3.x**:

http://jsfiddle.net/wasikuss/gx93rwnk/

But when I cloned from this my own fiddle with **Select2 4.0.x** it stopped working. The checkboxes are no longer presented. What's the issue?

http://jsfiddle.net/oa435z7s/

I copied all the elements from Fiddle 1 to Fiddle 2 by doing a direct Fork (Clone). Nothing was changed manually in the code. I only deleted the prior  Select2 CSS/JS and replaced them with 4.0.5. The Select2-MultiCheckboxes JS is exactly the same.

Also here's a JSFiddle where I updated the Raw Multi-Checkbox JS reference, the previous one had a Version 3.5 reference in its name:
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wasikuss/select2-multi-checkboxes/master/select2.multi-checkboxes.js
I assume this is the latest one?

http://jsfiddle.net/oa435z7s/2/
This is even worse.

Is there a new version of `Select2.Multi-Checkboxes.JS` that works with **Select2 4.0.x**?

Comment: This fiddle uses Select2 4.0.3: https://jsfiddle.net/wasikuss/7ak9skbb/

Comment: Could you summarize the changes?

Comment: I just find the right version to use, and also put the in the right loading order...for example this is your second fiddle with the updates http://jsfiddle.net/oa435z7s/8/

Comment: This second fiddle "with the updates" doesn't work. You can see it doesn't show checkboxes, for example.

Comment: It was just a css issue, http://jsfiddle.net/oa435z7s/10/

Comment: Thanks, is there a way to customize that header "1 > 6 total"?

Comment: Yeah, but you have to modify the plugin directly, like(check the line 67 of the javascript sandbox) http://jsfiddle.net/oa435z7s/13/

Comment: when using the above with select2 4.0.6-rc.1, it gives this error when any option is selected: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'selected' of undefined
    at d.select (select2.min.js:1)

Comment: also, @Hackerman can you please put the fiddle link as an answer to this question as any other who has this problem can refer to it.